# why found authenticated user wrong information in signalR hub server side code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a asp.net web application and I used asp.net signalR hub connection in this application. I am facing problem in case of multiple user login.

Think I have 2 client(in 2 browser) loggedIn in my application. I create hub connection after  a client logged into the application.I have also overridden the signalR hub onDisconnected() and OnConnected() method. But after successful login of two client in two browser using their respective  credential, when I try to refresh the page of any client it hits the server side signalR onDisconnected() method and then onConnected method as usual.

But the problem is when it hits onDisconnected() method I found the wrong authenticated user info. It always gives the authenticate userinfo of last logged In user.

But it works fine when it hits onConnected() method. It shows actual authenticated user info who refresh his page.

So if I refresh the last logged In user then it works fine. But if I refresh the first logged In user it found wrong authenticate user information.

And another thing is that I am getting the real hub ConnectionId in those two method.

Can anyone tell what's the problem?? Please feel free to ask any further questions or enquiry.

Comment: Can you make a sample project showing the problem?

Comment: I tried to repro but I see correct user is passed. Let's wait for Hannan's repro

public override Task OnDisconnected()
        {
            return Clients.All.hubReceived("Bye " + Context.User.Identity.Name + "!");
        }